# How to be notified when a SocketChannel is closed?

Tags: java, wrapper, nio

I want to be notified when a [`SocketChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) has its [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractInterruptibleChannel.html#close%28%29) method called. My first thought was to create a wrapper which notifies a listener when the `implCloseSelectableChannel` method is called (since the `close` method itself is declared `final` in `AbstractInterruptibleChannel`). This solution works, but when I tried to register it with a `Selector` I would get an `IllegalSelectorException` because of the following check in `SelectorImpl`:

```
/*     */   protected final SelectionKey register(AbstractSelectableChannel paramAbstractSelectableChannel, int paramInt, Object paramObject)
/*     */   {
/* 128 */     if (!(paramAbstractSelectableChannel instanceof SelChImpl))
/* 129 */       throw new IllegalSelectorException();
```

Now I can't override the `register` method to delegate to the wrapped `SocketChannel` because it's declared `final` in `AbstractSelectableChannel` and I can't implement `SelChImpl` because it has default visibility in the `sun.nio.ch` package. The only way I can see to proceed from here would be to make my own `SelectorProvider` and `Selector`, but that seems like overkill for something so simple.

Is there an easier way to be notified when a `SocketChannel` has been closed or do I need to rethink my program design?

`SocketChannelWrapper` example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketOption;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class SocketChannelWrapper extends SocketChannel {
    private static interface CloseListener {
        public void socketChannelClosed(SocketChannel channel);
    }

    private final SocketChannel socket;
    private final CloseListener listener;

    public SocketChannelWrapper(SocketChannel socket, CloseListener l) {
        super(socket.provider());
        this.socket = socket;
        listener = l;
    }

    @Override
    public SocketAddress getLocalAddress() throws IOException {
        return socket.getLocalAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getOption(SocketOption<T> name) throws IOException {
        return socket.getOption(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<SocketOption<?>> supportedOptions() {
        return socket.supportedOptions();
    }

    @Override
    public SocketChannel bind(SocketAddress local) throws IOException {
        return socket.bind(local);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> SocketChannel setOption(SocketOption<T> name, T value)
            throws IOException {
        return socket.setOption(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public SocketChannel shutdownInput() throws IOException {
        return socket.shutdownInput();
    }

    @Override
    public SocketChannel shutdownOutput() throws IOException {
        return socket.shutdownOutput();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket socket() {
        return socket.socket();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConnected() {
        return socket.isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConnectionPending() {
        return socket.isConnectionPending();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean connect(SocketAddress remote) throws IOException {
        return socket.connect(remote);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean finishConnect() throws IOException {
        return socket.finishConnect();
    }

    @Override
    public SocketAddress getRemoteAddress() throws IOException {
        return socket.getRemoteAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public int read(ByteBuffer dst) throws IOException {
        return socket.read(dst);
    }

    @Override
    public long read(ByteBuffer[] dsts, int offset, int length)
            throws IOException {
        return socket.read(dsts, offset, length);
    }

    @Override
    public int write(ByteBuffer src) throws IOException {
        return socket.write(src);
    }

    @Override
    public long write(ByteBuffer[] srcs, int offset, int length)
            throws IOException {
        return socket.write(srcs, offset, length);
    }

    @Override
    protected void implCloseSelectableChannel() throws IOException {
        socket.close();
        listener.socketChannelClosed(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void implConfigureBlocking(boolean block) throws IOException {
        socket.configureBlocking(block);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException,
            IOException {
        final Selector selector = Selector.open();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        selector.select();
                        Iterator<SelectionKey> itr = selector.selectedKeys()
                                .iterator();
                        while (itr.hasNext()) {
                            SelectionKey key = itr.next();
                            itr.remove();

                            if (key.isValid()) {
                                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                                    ((ServerSocketChannel) key.channel())
                                            .accept();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);

        ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open().bind(
                new InetSocketAddress(1234));
        server.configureBlocking(false);

        server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        t.start();

        SocketChannel socket = new SocketChannelWrapper(
                SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress
                        .getLocalHost(), 1234)), new CloseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void socketChannelClosed(SocketChannel channel) {
                        System.out.println("Socket closed!");
                    }
                });
        socket.configureBlocking(false);
        // socket.close(); //prints out "Socket closed!"
        socket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the `SocketChannel` is closed by you, you are closing it, so you can notify yourself any way you like.

If you want to be notified when the *peer* closes the *connection,*, `OP_READ` will fire and a read will return -1.

Comment: The problem is that if my program is to work right, I need whoever is closing the `SocketChannel` to notify me. If they don't, things start breaking. Call me lazy / forgetful but the easiest way to accomplish this would be to just have the callback right in the `SocketChannel`. I may need to rethink my design if this continues to be an issue.

Comment: @Jeffrey You need to debug your application.

Comment: I don't have bugs in my application, but if I forget to notify myself an error pops up. So far I have figured out the problem, had a "doh" moment and moved on, but one of these days I'm going to forget to notify myself and I won't be able to figure out why. I wanted to see if I could modify how `SocketChannel` worked to save me some trouble.

Comment: @Jeffrey I have miles of NIO code without notifications of closes. If you close the channel, its key is cancelled and it is deregistered from the Selector next time around. All I have is `if (!key.isValid()) continue;` in the select loop. If you need more than this I suggest there is something wrong with your design.

Comment: not if the peer does not do a proper shutdown...in that case you are not notifed and nothing fires.

Comment: @DeanHiller Define 'proper shutdown'. If you mean that the connection gets reset one way or the other, I agree. If you mean that the peer closes his socket without shutting it down first, I do not. NB The question is about closing.

Answer (score -1):

that's nasty.  you could maybe use a byte level aop package like http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/ (with aop you can should be able to add a cutpoint on the close method that does your callback).

you could also create a package with the same name as the sun package and implement the inteface in there.

but i can't see a good, clean way to do this.

Comment: Neither of those seem like very good programming practices, but I'll keep them in mind.

Comment: i agree.  i vaguely remember having this same problem years ago and not finding anything better.