# Can I fire an event when the socket is closed successfully in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

Reference to the Question I asked before, the socket closing need some times to operate:
[Why it warns me the socket is closed when I quit the programme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682003/why-it-warns-me-the-socket-is-closed-when-i-quit-the-programme)

```
        providerSocket.close();
```

Can I ask it to run several code when I close the socket? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say close needs some time to operate. As far as I know, close() is non-blocking. It returns right away.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why it warns me the socket is closed when I quit the programme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682003/why-it-warns-me-the-socket-is-closed-when-i-quit-the-programme)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran across [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9445973/758280) with `SocketChannel`s, and as far as I can tell (and as far as Stack Overflow can tell) there's no supported way to do this with the JDK. However, I didn't let that stop me. With proper encapsulation you can do something like this:

```
public class SocketWrapper implements Closeable {
    private final Socket socket;

    public SocketWrapper(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    /**
    * Provide all the methods you need in your application
    * for accessing the internal socket
    */

    public void close() throws IOException {
        socket.close();
        fireClosedEvent();
    }

    /**
    * Event firing methods, etc.
    */
}
```

This isn't as flexible as I would like and that's why I'm still leaving my question unanswered, but it might be a good solution for you. Of course, coming up with a better name than `SocketWrapper` might be a good idea.